# Advantages of heaps over binary trees in the Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, priority-queue, dijkstra

One standard implementation of the Dijkstra algorithm uses a heap to store distances from the starting node S to all unexplored nodes. The argument for using a heap is that we can efficiently pop the minimum distance from it, in `O(log n)`. However, to maintain the invariant of the algorithm, one also needs to update some of the distances in the heap. This involves:

- popping non-min elements from the heaps
- computing the updated distances
- inserting them back into the heap

I understand that popping non-min elements from a heap can be done in `O(log n)` if one knows the location of that element in the heap. However, I fail to understand how one can know this location in the case of the Dijkstra algorithm. It sounds like a binary search tree would be more appropriate.

More generally, my understanding is that the only thing that a heap can do better than a balanced binary search tree is to access (without removing) the min element. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I fail to understand how one can know this location in the case of the Dijkstra algorithm.

You need an additional array that keeps track of where in the heap the elements live, or an extra data member inside the heap's elements. This has to be updated after each heap operation.

> the only thing that a heap can do better than a balanced binary search tree is to access (without removing) the min element

Even a BST can be amended to keep a pointer to the min element in addition to the root pointer, giving O(1) access to the min (effectively amortizing the O(lg *n*) work over the other operations).

The only advantage of heaps in terms of worst-case complexity is the "heapify" algorithm, which turns an array into a heap by reshuffling its elements in-place, in linear time. For Dijkstra's, this doesn't matter, since it's going to do *n* heap operations of O(lg *n*) cost apiece anyway.

The real reason for heaps, then, is **constants**. A properly implemented heap is just a contiguous array of elements, while a BST is a pointer structure. Even when a BST is implemented inside an array (which can be done if the number of elements is known from the start, as in Dijkstra's), the pointers take up more memory, and navigating them takes more time than the integer operations that are used to navigate a heap.

Comment: I just read that heaps have a `DecreaseKey` function that updates a key inside a heap in `O(1)`. In that case I think the array you are suggesting is not needed (is it?). Also, I don't understand what you mean by the word "constants".

Comment: @user2564569: I've never seen a heap library that has "decrease-key" built-in, but if you find one, it's using the array or data member that I describe. And it's not O(1) but O(lg n), unless you use fancy heap structures such as Fibonacci heaps. By constants, I mean the hidden constants that you leave out when discussing complexity in big-O notation: heaps operations are faster than BST operations because they do less work.